# Mapping evil normal state Y to y$

Tags: evil

How can I redefine evil normal state `Y` to be equivalent to `y$` instead of `yy`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize the variable `evil-want-Y-yank-to-eol` to a non-nil value to get this behavior.